# VLOOKUP returns N/A when value exists

Tags: excel, vlookup

Using excel. I have this sample data (There's > 28,000 rows, just got a 7 row sample size)

[image]

I am using this formula `=VLOOKUP(new_q.csv!$A$67&new_q.csv!$B$67, A2:B28563, 4, FALSE)`  to try to match find a match in the above data, using the data source below **new_q.csv**. (The data is filtered, which is why I'm using A67, and B67 respectively)

[image]

Clearly row 2 in new_q.csv matches data from row 1 in the top data. Not only do I get a `!REF`, but before that reference error I received `#N/A` which can't be right, because the cell values match.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: With vlookup the entire lookup needs to be in the left most column.  You are looking for a string like: `9780544106644105` in column A in the other sheet.  Then the second issue is that the range in the second criterion only has two columns but you are trying to refer to the 4th.  The third criterion is the relative column of the range in the second to return.

Comment: Thanks, this helped clear things up. Basically I'm trying to query a combination of cell values together, like A:67&B:67. For this case, do I make the lookup in the entire left column, still?

Comment: if you want to use VLOOKUP, But since you are returning numbers SUMIFS should work if the combination of isbn and date are unique.  There are many ways to do this, look at the link above.  It goes through many different methods.